# Adobe Animate CC - Reused Button Not Working HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, button, adobe

I am having an issue with reusing the same button within an HTML5 canvas. The button needs to be reused over the course of several separate frames as well as several times within the same frame.

The button works correctly with the first use:

```
this.button_13.addEventListener("click", fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_24.bind(this));

function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_24()
{
    this.gotoAndStop(72);
}
```

At frame 72, I reuse the same button symbol with a new instance name. Unfortunately, this button does not work:

```
this.button_14.addEventListener("click", fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_25.bind(this));

function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_25()
{
    this.gotoAndStop(78);
}
```

Clicking this second button shows the button states, but will not advance the user to frame 78.

*If the 2nd button exists on the timeline for frame 72 only, it is not present in the published result at all. If the 2nd button exists on frame 72-77, the button is present but not functional.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this

```
this.button_13.removeEventListener("click", fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_24.bind(this));
```

before creating the second event listener.

Comment: Unfortunately, the button still doesn't work appropriately. I tried the same idea in a similar project. The first button has the event listener and a gotoandplay command attached to it.

The second button has the following code applied to it:
this.button_1.removeEventListener("click", fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame.bind(this));

this.button_2.addEventListener("click", fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame_2.bind(this));

function fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame_2()
{
 this.gotoAndPlay(345);
}

The second button moves me to frame 165 instead of 345.

Comment: You can not remove an event listener using "bind". The bind method creates another function, so it will not work. You have to save your original binding, and remove it instead -- or just `removeAllEventListeners`, which is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here.

1. Put your separate button instances on different layers.
2. Create one button instance on its own layer, have a script set the button's `visible` property (`true`/`false`) as needed, and modify your click handler to react based on the value of `this.currentFrame`.

Animate CC (2015.2 for me at the time of this writing) seems to generate its HTML 5 script output with animation in mind. When you have like object instances on multiple frames on the same layer, instead of creating a new instance of that object, it re-purposes the instance from a prior frame.

e.g. I create a dynamic text box named "myText" on frame 1. On frame 2, I create another dynamic text box and name it "myOtherText". When I publish and look at the script, the script calls Tween.to() first to place the "myText" object on the canvas and give it its appearance and position, then chains another .to() call to make myText look like myOtherText. *Under the hood, myOtherText simply doesn't exist*.

Creating another layer forces Animate to create the instances explicitly in CreateJS. However, if you have a lot of buttons, that could end up making a ton of layers and making your timeline look messy. I'd recommend option 1 if you only have a couple button instances, but for the latter case, option 2 may be the way to go.

1. Create a new layer. Name it whatever you want, like "button layer".
2. This layer will have only one keyframe.
3. Place your button instance on this layer. For continuity's sake, let's name it `button_13`.
4. Bind a `tick` handler to the root MovieClip (i.e. `this`) to handle whether the button should appear or not.

   ```
   var tickHandler = function () {
       switch (this.currentFrame) {
       //Add case statements for each frame you want the button to appear on
       //Remember, frame indexes in CJS are 0-based!
       case 12: case 13:
           this.button_13.visible = true;
           break;
       default:
           this.button_13.visible = false;
       }
   }.bind(this);
   this.removeEventListener('tick', tickHandler); //Make sure not to double-bind
   this.addEventListener('tick', tickHandler);
   ```
5. Bind a `click` handler to the button that will `gotoAndStop` on a frame dependent on the current frame.

   ```
   var clickHandler = function () {
       switch (this.currentFrame) {
       //Add case statements for each frame that should have a jump
       //Remember, frame indexes in CJS are 0-based!
       case 12:
           this.gotoAndStop(72);
           break;
       case 13:
           this.gotoAndStop(78);
           break;
       }
   }.bind(this) //Proxy the handler, as done above.
   this.button_13.removeEventListener('click', tickHandler); //Make sure not to double-bind
   this.button_13.addEventListener('click', tickHandler);
   ```
6. Place both of those scripts onto frame 1 of your movie.

I haven't tested this myself as presented, but it *should* accomplish what you're looking for.

Answer (score -1):

The solution is to move the instance on another layer. In that way, two different instances can be used in different images with different scripts and different names.